# Close IFrame Popup via JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, iframe

I have one Popup dialog. putting information after update or Insert that Information I want to close that dialog no luck with this

**aspx Page:**

```
 <div id="InnerVendorPopup" style="width: 900px; height: 420px">
        <iframe id="iframeVendor" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" width="900px" height="420px">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

**Master Page:**

```
 $("#InnerVendorPopup").dialog({
                height: 'auto',
                width: 920,
                title: 'Test',
                dialogClass: 'dialog_fixed',
                position: 'center',
                drag: function () {
                    $.data(this, 'dragged', true);
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').width($(".ui-widget-overlay").width() + 18);
                    $.data(this, 'dragged', false);
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').width($(".ui-widget-overlay").width() - 18);
                }

            });
```

**My C# Code:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myCloseScript", "closePopup();", true);
```

**My Javascript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    closePopup = function () {
        alert("call");
        $("#InnerVendorPopup").dialog("close");
    }
</script>
```

I want to close My Dialog popup after update or insert button click

Comment: do you get call alert

Comment: yes I got call alert

Comment: then just call $("#InnerVendorPopup").hide();

Comment: I did it but no luck

Comment: if javascript is in iframe try this $('#InnerVendorPopup', window.parent.document).hide();

Comment: yes its work for only iframe close but i want to close dialog